# Не определяется элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно взаимодействовать с такой структурой:

```js
$('tbody tr')[1].css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Добавьте клетки в таблицу.
2. Используйте `.eq()`, чтобы получить обертку jQuery вокруг элемента выборки.

```js
$('tbody tr').eq(1).css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>One</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Three</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```